# What is com.sec.android.intent.action.DVFS_BOOSTER and what's causing it?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've just found following warning in LogCat of my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 with 4.0.4:

```
10-26 20:29:27.456: W/ActivityManager(217): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent 
{ act=com.sec.android.intent.action.DVFS_BOOSTER flg=0x10 (has extras) } from
de.vsbsoft.schadenserfassung.android (pid=27302, uid=10016) requires 
com.sec.android.app.twdvfs.DVFS_BOOSTER_PERMISSION due to receiver 
com.sec.android.app.twdvfs/com.sec.android.app.twdvfs.TwDVFSBroadcastReceiver
```

I just didn't found it neither on developer.android nor on stackoverflow.com. Even [a search at Google](https://www.google.de/#hl=de&biw=1280&bih=677&sclient=psy-ab&q=dvfs_booster&oq=dvfs_booster&gs_l=hp.3..0i10i19.1313.3882.0.4321.12.12.0.0.0.0.316.2703.0j7j2j3.12.0...0.0...1c.1.GGE0OMg4pFM&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=f432d6e564c9b0a9&bpcl=35466521) didn't spit out what it is. Curious enough some of the top results there are related to Phonegap, which I don't use.

I just have a WebView for my webapp to provide PDF generation and some other simple stuff. So I think it has to do with any of the settings I'd made. Guessing by the package com.sec it seems like it has to do with some security feature. But what the heck stands `(tw)dvfs` for? Something with the **F**ile**S**ytem?

As far as I see the warning has no impact on my app, but the log says my app is requesting it. And so it is something I have to know from where it comes, what it means, if it is intelligent and when yes, is it friendly?

Jokes aside: I'm hoping that one of the gurus can give me a little peep inside that nirvana. I just don't have the time to comment out every line of my code until I found that needle inside a scratching haystack.

Comment: According to [this thread](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/35342-port-request-touchwiz-cameracamcorder-for-aosp-roms/) it seems to be a TouchWiz specific thing, possibly for voltage scaling. Are you using the camera?

Comment: Yes I do indirectly over the android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE action.

Comment: That's probably what it is then. I can't say for certain it's the camera usage, but it's definitely TouchWiz specific, and if it's only a warning, I would personally just ignore it.

Comment: I did since I asked this question ;). But I just wanted to know. Thank you a lot to point down what that `tw` thing is. Perhaps I will find the time to make a deeper analysis of it. You're right: at the moment it's O.K. to ignore it. But like the name says: We have to be warned and I hold that in mind for the case I will face a problem possibly relating ;) Even if I wouldn't accept it: make an answer and you get an up-vote ;)

Comment: I get it, even when I don't really use the camera, or the gallery. I do write to the SDcard frequently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cant answer your question fully but as to what D.V.F.S. is:

> Abstract :Dynamic Voltage and Frequency Scaling(DVFS) is the promising technology to reduce the power consumption of the embedded microprocessor[1](http://os.korea.ac.kr/publication_papers/domestic_confer/IEMEK_thlee.pdf). Since there is a trade-off between the performance and the power consumption, performance demand of system should be considered while using DVFS in real embedded system. As a result, the DVFS is restrictively exploited in real-time task which has definite performance demand and execution deadlines. The DVFS policy, that is adopted by smart phone, is on-demand. The on-demand policy changes CPU frequency and voltage when workload of CPU has been changed. This paper suggest power management policy for android device. It control system frequency that considered by characteristic of application‘s workload. For this, implement android medial player application. It request DVFS to kernel when changed it's workload

[Link to Paper with above abstract*](http://os.korea.ac.kr/publication_papers/domestic_confer/IEMEK_thlee.pdf)

*the paper is in Korean...

Comment: Thanks, that's a hint to clear the fog a little. So granting the requested permission should improve the proportion of performance to power used by the app. Just now I'm working on another project, but I will keep it in mind to check it when possible.